# Using concurrency to have backWorker .swf (animation on displayList) to use it in mainWorker app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have main application app.swf to which I embed backWorker.swf which contains just animated MovieClip which is added to stage (backWorker's stage). As my main application load and initialize all the content (unfortunately I can not shift this functionality to backWorker) I wanted to have loading animation (fake preloader) in the backWorker. I successfully established communication between these two (through MessageChannel - I try to use send() and receive() methods to gets content from back to main worker), but have no idea how to render (by adding to stage with addChild()) backWorker.swf in its own proccess as I cast the backWorker.swf file as byteArray object in app.swf
Is it even possible ?

Comment: you call a lot of things "worker" but those are not workers are they? They're just simple movies right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't show display objects in your `Worker` instance as it doesn't have a stage. If you wish to show a progress bar, you'll have to show it in the main application. In fact, from your description, you're doing the exact reverse of what should be done - have the main .swf show the progress and the worker doing the heavy processing in the background.

Comment: thanks for instant response. Yes, I know thats exact reverse of how it should look, I will try to change an architecture of the app, if it is possible.